# How do I reference files located outside of the src folder in a vue project?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a vue application that is pulling documents from a database and writing them to a directory at the project directory level of my vue app. The folder structure looks something like this:

```
+---Files
|   \---Work
tests__
+---public
\---src
    +---assets
    +---components
    +---includes
    +---mixins
    +---plugins
    +---router
    +---services
    +---store
    \---views
```

The files are located in the Files/Work directory. Inside my component, I am trying to create an anchor tag that sets the href to the location of the file.

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/Files/Work/my_file.pdf" download="my_file.pdf">
    Download
</a>
```

When I set the tag like this, the chrome download says "failed - No File", instead of properly downloading the file. When pasting the above URL into the address bar, the application routes to show the navigation bar, but an empty VMain.

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your HTTP server to serve the files and then use URLs that said server recognises.

You can't drop files into any old location on your disk and then expect the HTTP server you have running to make them public. That would be a huge security problem!

The test server provided by the Vue 2 CLI will give URLs to [files in the public directory](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling) (I note that you aren't putting the files there at the moment). You could also host them on a separate HTTP server.

You'll need to ensure that your production environment has matching URLs.